# Pulling data from a structure?

Tags: c++

i currently have this code

```
    struct Students {
        int studentID;
        char firstName[12];
        char lastName[12];
        char email[25];
    };

    void showStudentAddMenu()
    {
        int i;
        cout << "How many students would you like to add? (Max 10) ";
        cin >> addStudentNumber;
        Students student[10];

        for (i = 0; i < addStudentNumber; i++)
        {
            cout << "Student ID: ";
            cin >> student[i].studentID;
            cout << "Students first name: ";
            cin >> student[i].firstName;
            cout << "Student last name: ";
            cin >> student[i].lastName;
            cout << "Student email: ";
            cin >> student[i].email;
        }
    }
    void studentLookup()
    {
        Students student[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            cout << "Student ID: " << student[i].studentID << endl;
            cout << "Student first name: " << student[i].firstName << endl;
            cout << "Student last name: " << student[i].lastName << endl;
            cout << "Student email: " << student[i].email << endl;
        }
    }
int main()
{
    do
    {
        showMainMenu();
        cin >> selector;
        if (selector == 1)
        {
            showStudentAddMenu();
        }
        else if (selector == 2)
        {
            studentLookup();
        }
        else if (selector == 3)
        {

        }
        else if (selector == 4)
        {

        }
        else if (selector == 5)
        {
            exit(0);
        }
    } while (selector != 5);
return 0;
}
```

but I'm struggling to pull the data from the structure itself, I just have a bunch of random characters being returned after I input a users data, and try to pull it.

```
Student ID: -858993460
Student first name: ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠Éºm0ê²V
Student last name: ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠Éºm0ê²V
Student email: ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠Éºm0ê²V
```

I have a feeling I need to include pointers somehow but I am completely lost and any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Do you want to display a data of **ONE** student or **ALL**?

Comment: im looking to display all atm and I can later refine it. I'm assuming that would just be the for loop to limit the users I display

Comment: *I have a feeling I need to include pointers somehow* -- Why aren't you using `std::string` instead of `char` arrays?  Second `Students student[10];` -- why are you declaring a brand new array inside of `studentLookup`?  It looks like you are under the miconception that `Students student[10];` is the same `Students student[10];` declared in your other function -- it isn't.

Comment: Also, please post the `main` program you are using.  Probably there are mistakes / misconceptions in that function also.

Comment: Looks like uninitialised memory, reading the ID probably failed causing all subsequent operations to fail, you should check the stream state after every read

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie removing the Students student[10]; from the studentLookup gives me a "no operator [] matches these operands" error, the main is just a do while loop but ill post as well, ill check changing into strings though. Also put the main function in the op.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my gesture, you've called all the 10 `students` struct, since not all of them are filled by the user, it shows some garbage. I've made a dynamic program which reads the `limit` by the user and defines the arrayed struct.

Look at the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

const int MAX = 10;
int limit = 0;

struct Students {
    int studentID;
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    string email;
} student[MAX];

void addStudentsPrompt(void);
void studentLookup(void);

int main(void) {

    addStudentsPrompt();
    studentLookup();

    return 0;
}

void addStudentsPrompt(void) {
    std::cout << "How many students to register? (Max 10) ";
    std::cin >> limit;

    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        std::cout << "Student ID: ";
        std::cin >> student[i].studentID;

        std::cout << "Students first name: ";
        std::cin >> student[i].firstName;

        std::cout << "Student last name: ";
        std::cin >> student[i].lastName;

        std::cout << "Student email: ";
        std::cin >> student[i].email;

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

void studentLookup(void) {
    int getSize = sizeof(student) / sizeof(student[0]);

    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        std::cout << "Student ID: " << student[i].studentID << std::endl
             << "Student first name: " << student[i].firstName << std::endl
             << "Student last name: " << student[i].lastName << std::endl
             << "Student email: " << student[i].email << std::endl << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Simply two void functions used which sets and gets the data defined by the user. I recommend you using the `string` rather than applying character array for better results as I've done in the above code.

> **Example Output**

```
// --- stdin ---
How many students to register? (Max 10) 2
Student ID: 100 
Students first name: Hello
Student last name: World
Student email: Helloworld@gmail 

Student ID: 101
Students first name: john
Student last name: Doe
Student email: johndoe@something
// --- stdout ---
Student ID: 100
Student first name: Hello
Student last name: World
Student email: Helloworld@gmail

Student ID: 101
Student first name: john
Student last name: Doe
Student email: johndoe@something
```

Enjoy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

`Students` should be named `Student` because it only contains information about *one* student.

You currently declare `Students student[10];` locally in each function. Each array is unique and what you enter in one function will not be visible outside the function in which it was declared. You need to pass the information to the functions using it.

Since the user of the program is free to enter any number of students, use a `std::vector` to store them. A `std::vector` can grow dynamically.

Instead of having a `char[]` with a hardcoded lenght for `name` etc., use `std::string`. It will, just like `std::vector`, grow dynamically.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Student {
    int studentID;
    std::string firstName;
    std::string lastName;
    std::string email;
};

// a function to print one student
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Student& s) {
    return os
        << "Student ID: " << s.studentID << '\n'
        << "Student first name: " << s.firstName << '\n'
        << "Student last name: " << s.lastName << '\n'
        << "Student email: " << s.email << '\n'
    ;
}

// return a std::vector<Student>
std::vector<Student> showStudentAddMenu()
{
    using std::cin, std::cout;

    std::vector<Student> students;

    cout << "How many students would you like to add? ";

    // check that extraction was successful before using addStudentNumber:
    if(size_t addStudentNumber; cin >> addStudentNumber) {
        students.reserve(addStudentNumber);
        Student s;

        for (size_t i=0; i<addStudentNumber; ++i)
        {
            cout << "Student ID: ";
            cin >> s.studentID;
            cout << "Students first name: ";
            cin >> s.firstName;
            cout << "Student last name: ";
            cin >> s.lastName;
            cout << "Student email: ";
            if(cin >> s.email)
                students.push_back(s); // store one student
            else
                break;                 // if input failed
        }
    }
    return students;
}

void studentLookup(const std::vector<Student>& students)
{
    // print all students
    for (const Student& s : students)
    {
        std::cout << s; // using our operator<< that we defined under Student
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<Student> students = showStudentAddMenu();
    studentLookup(students);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fields of the struct are not null-terminated, thus they are not valid C-strings and cannot be printed like ones.

For a struct defined this way compiler would know the size of each field, so you can print them with something like:

```
Student student {...};
std::cout << std::string_view(student.firstName, sizeof(Students::firstName)) << std::endl;
```